# magento shipping

Tags: php, magento

I have recently created a new shipping module in Magento 1.3.2 with the aid of the Magento developers guide. My module works correctly, however I cant seem to work how to get the functionality for it to become apart of the carriers down down list when a shipment is created within the admin area.

Once I have my carrier in this drop down list, I am going to need to apply additional functionality so that if my carrier is selected when the shipment order is placed then it does a whole heap of things.

So things i need to work out are:

1. How can make my shipment option a carrier in the drop down list
2. What class must I extend to add the functionality or can I simply add it to my shipment model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you added the necessary blocks under `app/code/local/yournamespace/yourmodule/Blocks/Adminhtml`and a layout xml file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout`?

Comment: I don't. Do you have a sample of what these should look like? I am searching around as we speak. I will post if i find anything

Comment: Probably the best option is to find a community extension for a shipping module on Magento Connect and use that as a model.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the problem.

The overall problem was that I had not set the method isTrackingAvailable() (within my shipping model) to return true.

For anyone wondering how to worked that out.

I looked through all of the templates files related to shipping. Once I found the file, I found where the drop down list was being created:

```
 <?php foreach ($this->getCarriers() as $_code=>$_name): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $_name; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

After seeing that is was being called using $this. I did a echo get_class($this) to find the class name that was calling it, which was Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Shipment_Create_Tracking.

In there is where i found getCarriers() function.

In there it was collecting all of the carriers by creating an object called Mage_Shipping_Model_Config.

```
$carrierInstances = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getAllCarriers(
            $this->getShipment()->getStoreId()
);
```

and calling its function getAllCarriers().

Inside this function it returned all of the carriers from the core_config_data table in the db.

So jumping back to the getCarriers() function.. we now have all the carriers. A little further down I could see that there was an IF statement that asked is the carrier had the function isTrackingAvailable() returning true before it would return the carrier.

```
    foreach ($carrierInstances as $code => $carrier) {
        if ($carrier->isTrackingAvailable()) {
            $carriers[$code] = $carrier->getConfigData('title');
        }
    }
```

If anyone has any questions.. email me. mark@mbwebstudios.com (mind you I'm still learning myself but I will answer any questions as best I can)

Comment: Thanks for the update Mark.  By the way, you can turn on the Template and Block hints for the Admin interface, so you don't have to do the `echo get_class($this)`.  In `core_config_data`, insert a row with scope=websites, scope_id=0, value=1 and path = 'dev/debug/template_hints'.  Repeat for scope=websites, scope_id=0,  value = 1 and path = 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks'.  Alternatively, install the HM_DeveloperToolbar from Magento Connect and click the convenient link!